# Neos Multiple Sites

Tags: neoscms

Is it possible to manage multiple sites in `Neos` with shared content and templates? I tried to do it under the directory sites but I am not sure yet where to put it correctly. Also I was thinking about using the language dropdown maybe? What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Neos can manage multiple sites with shared content and templates. To create a new site you might want to create a new *site package* using the *Sites Management* administration module.

You then have to assign different domains to your sites to have them accessible with the Neos backend, they will show up under *Content* in the menu.

From within one site package you can refer to templates with `resource://My.First.Site/Private/Templates/NodeTypes/Test.html` and you can include TypoScript from another site using something like `include: resource://My.First.Site/Private/TypoScript/NodeTypes/*`.

With Flow Query you can as well access content of another site by using an absolute path to nodes:

```
items = ${q(site).find('/sites/myfirstsite/some-node')
```

Note though that all configuration in `NodeTypes.yaml` as well as `Settings.yaml` is global and will be combined from all active sites.